# How to create notification for a site?

Tags: html, web, push-notification, notifications

There is this site that i have to check every time to see if there is any new available house to rent and i was wondering if it's possible to program a notification for it to not miss my chance. If there is any way to do that please tell me how.

Comment: How about [sken.io](https://www.sken.io/)?

Answer (score 0):

one way is:
You can use python to do that,
you need a Bot (Automation) that will check the availability of the Thing you are looking for, difficulty depends upon the site.